# Php/MySql Polygon insertion

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Mysql data base table polygons and a field as latlon. When am inserting following query as

```
INSERT INTO polygons SET polygons.latlon = GeomFromText('POLYGON(( 28.181365 -25.874693, 28.180419 -25.874313, 28.180177 -25.873869, 28.180236 -25.87377, 28.181557 -25.873095, 28.181782 -25.873173, 28.181871 -25.873357, 28.18174700000001 -25.873426, 28.181959 -25.873838, 28.18267000000001 -25.873338, 28.183323 -25.872918, 28.184112 -25.872499, 28.184907 -25.872125, 28.185294 -25.871959, 28.18587 -25.871776, 28.186254 -25.871709, 28.186856 -25.87169000000001, 28.187051 -25.871255, 28.187372 -25.870961, 28.188084 -25.870562, 28.188201 -25.870713, 28.187426 -25.871118, 28.187184 -25.87134800000001, 28.187059 -25.871679, 28.18796800000001 -25.871907, 28.187878 -25.872046, 28.187021 -25.871787, 28.186193 -25.871833, 28.185301 -25.872108, 28.184396 -25.872514, 28.18467 -25.872961, 28.184454 -25.873065, 28.184185 -25.872605, 28.183725 -25.872816, 28.183279 -25.87313, 28.182548 -25.873597, 28.18219 -25.873924, 28.181972 -25.874078, 28.181397 -25.874637))')
```

Then it will show an error as

> ## 1048 - Column 'latlon' cannot be null

.

Comment: sql insert queries should be `INSERT INTO tbl_sort('id', 'sort_alphanum') VALUES ([value-1],[value-2])` SET is used to update like `UPDATE tbl_sort SET id=[value-1],sort_alphanum=[value-2] WHERE 1`

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the following for INSERT:

```
SET @g = 'POLYGON(( 28.181365 -25.874693, 28.180419 -25.874313, 28.180177 -25.873869, 28.180236 -25.87377, 28.181557 -25.873095, 28.181782 -25.873173, 28.181871 -25.873357, 28.18174700000001 -25.873426, 28.181959 -25.873838, 28.18267000000001 -25.873338, 28.183323 -25.872918, 28.184112 -25.872499, 28.184907 -25.872125, 28.185294 -25.871959, 28.18587 -25.871776, 28.186254 -25.871709, 28.186856 -25.87169000000001, 28.187051 -25.871255, 28.187372 -25.870961, 28.188084 -25.870562, 28.188201 -25.870713, 28.187426 -25.871118, 28.187184 -25.87134800000001, 28.187059 -25.871679, 28.18796800000001 -25.871907, 28.187878 -25.872046, 28.187021 -25.871787, 28.186193 -25.871833, 28.185301 -25.872108, 28.184396 -25.872514, 28.18467 -25.872961, 28.184454 -25.873065, 28.184185 -25.872605, 28.183725 -25.872816, 28.183279 -25.87313, 28.182548 -25.873597, 28.18219 -25.873924, 28.181972 -25.874078, 28.181397 -25.874637))';

INSERT INTO polygons (latlon) VALUES (GeomFromText(@g));
```